# Access all items inside List<T> in a random order

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a List where T has a property CoverImage. I want to access all items inside the list in a random order and load the appropriate image from server. I am not interested in loading data from server, all I want to know is how to access all the elements inside that list in a random way and only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
foreach(var elem in list.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()))
{

}
```

Comment: Or just to shuffle, `list.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())`

Comment: @Rati_Ge It's O(n*log(n)) in speed.  It's simple enough to get O(n) out of a shuffle.  Also important when shuffling is ensuring it's "fair" and that it doesn't have a bias for certain items to be higher/lower in the sequence.

Comment: @Rati_Ge, No As Servy said, `Fisher–Yates shuffle` can be the most performant way. How many items do we talk about 1 million?

Comment: @I4V Well, I wouldn't say *most* performant. The wikipedia page I linked to shows others that can potentially be faster, but they'll all have the same big oh value of O(n).  It's the average cases (as opposed to worst case) or speed at a lower granularity, that can improve.

Comment: @Servy, Do you have to comment on every answer? I just showed the simplest way and it is not the best performant way. So what do you want me to do? Delete the answer?

Comment: @I4V, I would like to see you add something *to the answer* that says there are better options available, perhaps mention one of them, and that if you are *in a pinch* and have a relatively low need for performant code (small inputs, etc.), this will certainly work. If you were to do that, I would remove the downvote I gave you.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram All that is already said in the comments. Keep your downvote.

Comment: @I4V, comments aren't answers and can be deleted. They are not first class citizens of this Q&A system.

Comment: @I4V When the answerer has the viewpoint that they don't need to make the answer good, the comments will "fix" it, then yeah, I'll have a comment for many of those answers.  For the people that take a lot of time and effort to write correct, detailed, and well written answers, I find I have less comments.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate term for this is *shuffling*.  Shuffling is the concept of re-ordering a collection/sequence into a random order.

There are many means of doing so, with varying performance implications.  A great choice is the F[isher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

The pseudocode:

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Comment: and if you don't want to modify the original list, create a new integer array of 0-n, shuffle that array, then iterate over the array, using the value list[index[i]]

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random();
List<T> myListRnd = new List<T>();

int p = 0;
while (myList.Count > 0)
{
    p = r.Next(myList.Count + 1)
    myListRnd.Add(myList[p]);
    myList.RemoveAt[p];
}
```

Comment: Fairly high probability of running into an IndexOutOfRangeException. If I have 10 items in my list, you take Count + 1 to get a number less than 11. That number could be 10. However, the maximum index in the list would be 9.

Comment: Also note that removing an item from an arbitrary position in a `List` is not efficient, this is an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in writing your own extension method, it might look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Random random)
{
    List<T> itemList = new List<T>(enumerable);

    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; ++i)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.Next(itemList.Count);
        if (randomIndex != i)
        {
            T temp = itemList[i];
            itemList[i] = itemList[randomIndex];
            itemList[randomIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

    return itemList;
}
```

Comment: ok but I do not want to modify original list all i wanted to to is to access its elements randomly. I wanted to created fade-in effect for image load which happeneds using async/await so there is some sort of nice mosaic fade-in effect now

Comment: I've modified it so that it no longer modifies the original list.

Comment: Careful when using `yield return`, when you use it the body of the function will get executed every time the result is iterated over.  Which is why I/O in a function using `yield return` is a potentially bad idea. If you iterate over the results from your Shuffle extension method more than once the order will be different.  Just returning `itemList` would work.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's reshuffling itemList every time it returns an item? My testing doesn't seem to agree with that. I do see that simply return the itemList is sufficient, so I'll modify the code in that manner.

Comment: No, I'm saying that as a result of the `yield return` it is reshuffled everytime the result of the extension method gets iterated over.  Look at the output from the following code      var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var shuffle = array.Shuffle(new Random());
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 foreach (var num in shuffle)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(num);
 }
 Console.WriteLine();
}